# Using AngularJS Controllers created with angular.module().controller()

Tags: angularjs

I am still very new to AngularJS and am working through setting up my first application.  I would like to be able to do the following:

```
angular.module('App.controllers', [])
  .controller('home', function () {
    $scope.property = true;
  }]);

angular.module('App', ['App.controllers'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: home});
  }]);
```

Using this setup the following error is generated:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: home is not defined from App
```

My question is: How can I register controllers using `angular.module.controller()` (or `$controllerProvider.register()` directly) and use the registered controller elsewhere in my app.

My motivation: I would like to avoid using either global constructor functions as my controllers (as most of the examples on angularjs.org use) or complex namespacing.  If I can register and use controllers as single variable names (that are not then put in the global scope) that would be ideal.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Try using a string identifier.

`routeProvider.when('/', {templateUrl: 'partials/home.html', controller: 'home'});`

When you use a literal, it is looking for a variable called `home`, but that doesn't exist in this case.

Comment: The above solution doesn't appear to work... I'm getting "Error: Argument 'PhoneListCtrl' is not a function, got string". Help!

Comment: If you define the controller as a function (`function PhoneListCtrl(){}`), you have to reference it as a function.  If you define it with .controller (`app.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function(){})`, you should reference it as a string.

Comment: I used string identifier to assign a controller from another module, and it works. very nice!

Comment: Using a string worked for me on the routeProvider, but now this is not working: <div ng-controller="MyCtrl"></div>. The other form works - <div class="ng-controller='MyCtrl'"></div>, but I'd prefer using the attribute form because it's simpler. Is there a way?

Comment: That should work, Joe.  Could you create a plunker?  http://plnkr.co/edit -> New -> AngularJS

Comment: Adam, I had the problem continue happening to me as well, but in the end, the problem was my controller was using a service (created with a factory) and it was the link between the module and the service that was the problem. I would try investigating there. 

I ended up using the same name for the module as the service because I was thinking in the mindset of module('mymodule').controller where you want the same name, but not for a service. So when including ['ngResource'] redeclares the controller and wiped out what I had for the controller.

Comment: What if you want to return that function as a module (export it in an object literal)? Ideally say `return { main: app.controller('MainCtrl') };  // should return this function`. Can you do this?

Answer (score -1):

If you are getting controller is not defined error you have to write your controller name within the quotes.

or define your controller like this

```
function controllerName()
{
   //your code here
}
```

refer this: [Uncaught ReferenceError:Controller is not defined in AngularJS](http://coding-issues.blogspot.in/2013/07/uncaught-referenceerrorcontroller-is.html)