# Getting controller reference in service with $controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

I am new to Angular, but I am working on a service class that I have need to get a reference to a Controller by name.

This particular service is used in the navigation, and setups a listener on `$stateChangeStart`:

```
var NavServiceFactory = function($state, $rootScope) {
  var NavService = function() {
    this.orgStates = {};
    this.pageTracker = {};
    var self = this;
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState) {
      // This is where I need to get the controller from the fromState
    });
  };

  var proto = NavService.prototype;

  // ... //

  return new NavService();
};

app.factory('navService', NavServiceFactory);

module.exports = app;
```

I marked where I need to get to the controller.  The purpose is that I want to call a method to see if the user has properly filled in some required data so I can mark that nav item as "completed".  I marked where I need the controller.

What I have tried is to inject the `$controller` into the Service and the Service Factory, but neither seemed to work at all.  The goal is to try to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707693/angularjs-get-controller-function-by-string) and provide a means that the controller for the page content can determine the "doneness" of the page navigation. Is it possible to get $controller into my service as an injected dependency?  We are using Angular 1.4, I believe.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of services to detach logic from controllers?

Comment: I would find a different pattern, a service should not know about the controller. This would be very difficult to test for properly.  You could set up an event the controller knows about (broadcast, etc).

Comment: also you could but the $stateChangeStart in the controller..

Comment: This seems like it needs to work on the state.  Is there a better pattern for getting to the state that would better match the spirit of the Service class?