# AngularJS Uncaught ReferenceError: controller is not defined from module

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have the following code;

```
var app =
    angular.
        module("myApp",[]).
        config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/someplace', {
                templateUrl: 'sometemplate.html',
                controller: SomeControl
             });
             // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
             $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        });

app.controller('SomeControl', ...);
```

I get the following error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: SomeControl is not defined from myApp
```

Is the problem just that I can not use app.controller('SomeControl', ...) syntax? when using $routeProvider? is the only working syntax:

```
function SomeControl(...)
```

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211999/using-angular-controllers-created-with-angular-module-controller

Comment: Thanks @KarlZilles - I searched, but missed that one.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use quotes:

```
            controller: 'SomeControl'
```

Comment: DUH, Thanks for finding my small mistake ;)

Answer (score 8):

Like Foo L said, you need to put quotes around `SomeControl`. If you don't use quotes, you are referring to the variable `SomeControl`, which is undefined because you did not use a named function to represent the controller.

When you use the alternative that you mentioned, `function SomeControl(...)`, you define that named function. Otherwise, Angular needs to know that it needs to look up the controller in the `myApp` module.

Using the `app.controller('SomeControl', ...)` syntax is better because it does not pollute the global namespace.

Answer (score 1):

The above answers are correct however, this error can also happen :

1. If the name of the controller in you html or jsp etc page is not matching the actual cotnroller

`<div ng-controller="yourControllerName as vm">`

2. Also if the name of the function controller does not match the controller definition then this error can happen too.

`angular.module('smart.admin.vip')
            .controller('yourController', yourController);
function yourController($scope, gridSelections, gridCreationService, adminVipService) {
            var vm = this;
            activate();`